Adding another author to a paper that hasn’t contributed?
I’m a non traditional postbacc student have been working in a medical clinic for the past 2 years. I have been working on a case report for months. Almost done… just working on the introduction and conclusion. 2 weeks ago a college student (rising junior) came to clinic and my professor wants to add him to the paper. By the way, he has never seen the patient discussed in the case report. He is leaving in a week and hasn’t done anything for the paper. He has started working on his project with the professor. I’m unsure how he could help since I’m almost done and he is unfamiliar with the science/the field. Should this student be included in the paper even though he just came and hasn’t contributed? I don’t think it would be fair…

You should first ask your advisor why he should be added. He may have contributions but you don't know.

Thank you for your response. He hasn’t. For example, the paper is on a specific cancer and on certain drugs for treatment and during clinic visits, he asks me to spell the name of the cancer and the name of the drugs.

Then I would tell your supervisor that you don't believe this person should be included as an author for the reasons you mention, and ask for their advice/decision.

You don't know what you don't know.

@melissabe I'd recommend to ask the advisor regardless of whether you are convinced that "he hasn't". You'd want to understand their reasoning, don't you? (You may not agree with it but anyway...)

In your shoes I would feel annoyed.
But I have questions:

How long have you been working on this report– two months or much longer?
Why haven't you asked your professor? Do you have a difficult relationship?
Were you advised or told? It seems the latter, in which case do a little sleuthing  and discover how your professor knows this student so well that he recommends that his name be added in the report. If nothing suspicious turns up, then you'll probably have no choice but to follow your professor's instructions.
This college student arrived in the clinic two weeks ago and is going to leave next week. Can you include this information in the acknowledgements? This would make it clear that his contributions were added when the bulk of the  report had already been written.
For example,


My thanks to XXX for his words of support, and acute analysis of bla, bla, bla… in the last month of writing this report.


It would be strange to refer to an author in the acknowledgements; are you suggesting this as an alternative to including them as an author, or in addition?

@BryanKrause I would make sure whatever contributions were made by the newcomer to acknowledge them in the paper, and to include at least one time-date. If the OP has spent four or more months on the paper, it is incomprehensible why a stranger's name should be added, mere weeks before it is peer reviewed and/or published. First the OP needs to ask their professor, investigate and then, if possible, challenge the professor's recommendation. If there are there three or four authors, a quick mention of the third (or fourth) author could also be included in the  acknowledgements.

You do not put authors in the Acknowledgements section. That section is to recognize contributions by non-authors.

@BryanKrause  First the professor owes the OP an explanation. Failing that, perhaps a compromise could be agreed on, a few sentences  in the acknowledgement dedicated to the college student's contributions and leave it as that. If the OP has been working on the paper for "only" two or three months then it's not worth the battle, and chalk it up as one of life's experiences. We don't have all the background info, ergo I said "I have questions" I was hoping for a little clarification at this point.

Okay, but besides all the questions in your answer, which are not an answer, the only suggestion you provide is to suggest using the acknowledgements section to label their contributions as minimal with a passive-aggressive shot that they only were involved for a month.


Should this student be included in the paper even though he just came and hasn’t contributed?

Well, in an ideal world, decisions on authorship weigh the contributions of each proposed author as the primary if not exclusive defining factor. Also, such decisions on authorship status are nominally worked out if not in advance of the publication at least at any point along the way when a change is proposed via congenial discussion among all proposed authors. Taking your statements as gospel, the answer to including the student as co-author is no, and the approach being taken to include the student at the last minute without discussion is professionally disrespectful and potentially unfair.
In the real world, politics and emotions get involved to skew the decision process, often unfavorably and unfairly, as you are experiencing. Based on your background information, your advisor is making an executive decision to overrule the respected approach to determine authorship. You will have to decide your path forward.

Accept and move on. Your professional life will not be defined by this one personal and professional insult, especially as your statements suggest you are quite early in your career by normal standards. At best, argue for a clear statement of author contributions at the end of the article if the journal supports such statements. Otherwise, nod in agreement, finish your work, and look for the next (and better) opportunity all the wiser.

Confront and demand equitable treatment. This can be done in a professional manner. An opening question to your advisor might simply be to ask how the decision to add the student keeps in line with your understanding of what authorship means. Perhaps by example your advisor is under the (ill-conceived) belief that authors are just the folks who happen to be working in any way even minimally on the project at the time of the publication. You may have no battle to win here, or you may have a chance to educate yourself and your advisor both. The first option to accept and move on is always at your command as needed.

Withdraw your contribution. This is the "I am taking my ball home and leaving you pick up the pieces" approach. Rarely is this the wisest choice. But at least you should see it as the furtherest extreme measure that could be taken (but should not).


You are not the first in this situation, and it is not always an easy one to resolve. I hope my answers provide sufficient background to help you decide where to go next.
